# why mongodb does not create chunk for a sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I had a mongo instance running that was the only node in its replicaset. It had about 33G of data. Now I added 2 other shards each only one node in their replicaset and added them to cluster using `db.addShard` command. Then I ran `sh.enableSharding('mydb')` and sharded my collection using command `sh.shardCollection('mydb.user', {_id: 1})`. First of all I expect the balancer to balance my data across three shards, which did not happen. Also when I run `sh.status()` in the output I see that it hasn't created any chunk. However when I run `db.user.getShardDistribution()` it shows that data is distributed. I am so confused. Can some one please help me?
results of sh.status():

```
shardingVersion
{
  _id: 1,
  minCompatibleVersion: 5,
  currentVersion: 6,
  clusterId: ObjectId("64d62ba7e9d199311e7be6b5")
}
---
shards
[
  {
    _id: 'myshard1',
    host: 'myshard1/node3:27018',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp(6, 1691758010)
  },
  {
    _id: 'myshard2',
    host: 'myshard2/node2:27018',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp(206, 1691773056)
  },
  {
    _id: 'myshard3',
    host: 'myshard3/node1:27018',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp(51, 1691773082)
  }
]
---
active mongoses
[ { '6.0.4': 1 } ]
---
autosplit
{ 'Currently enabled': 'yes' }
---
balancer
{
  'Currently enabled': 'yes',
  'Currently running': 'yes',
  'Collections with active migrations': [
    'mydb.user started at Fri Aug 11 2023 22:51:42 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)'
  ],
  'Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts': 0,
  'Migration Results for the last 24 hours': {
    '48': "Failed with error 'aborted', from myshard1 to myshard3",
    '1243': 'Success'
  }
}
---
databases
[
  {
    database: {
      _id: 'mydb',
      primary: 'myshard1',
      partitioned: false,
      version: {
        uuid: UUID("2dcac9aa-595c-4515-8033-27298507f20c"),
        timestamp: Timestamp(1, 1691758436),
        lastMod: 1
      }
    },
    collections: {
      'mydb.user': {
        shardKey: { _id: 1 },
        unique: false,
        balancing: true,
        chunks: [],
        tags: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    database: { _id: 'config', primary: 'config', partitioned: true },
    collections: {
      'config.system.sessions': {
        shardKey: { _id: 1 },
        unique: false,
        balancing: true,
        chunks: [],
        tags: []
      }
    }
  }
]
```

result of db.user.getShardingDistribution():

```
Shard myshard1 at myshard1/node3:27018
{
  data: '279.63GiB',
  docs: 241723,
  chunks: 0,
  'estimated data per chunk': '0B',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 0
}
---
Shard myshard2 at myshard2/node2:27018
{
  data: '252.49GiB',
  docs: 66054,
  chunks: 0,
  'estimated data per chunk': '0B',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 0
}
---
Shard myshard3 at myshard3/node1:27018
{
  data: '252.59GiB',
  docs: 18772,
  chunks: 0,
  'estimated data per chunk': '0B',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 0
}
---
Totals
{
  data: '784.73GiB',
  docs: 326549,
  chunks: 0,
  'Shard myshard1': [
    '35.63 % data',
    '74.02 % docs in cluster',
    '1.18MiB avg obj size on shard'
  ],
  'Shard myshard2': [
    '32.17 % data',
    '20.22 % docs in cluster',
    '3.91MiB avg obj size on shard'
  ],
  'Shard myshard3': [
    '32.18 % data',
    '5.74 % docs in cluster',
    '13.77MiB avg obj size on shard'
  ]
}
```

Actual data size on each node:

```
13G node1
13G node2
33G node3
```

Comment: Command `getShardingDistribution()` does not exist. Where did you execute this?

Comment: Maybe this bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-43689 was added again.

Comment: Sharding with _id, without doing it hashed is (sorry) stupid! Newer shard with _id directly, always hash it. Now every "new" document is stored always to same node.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry, I meant getShardDistribution. I will edit it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I believed mongodb will split chunks based on available data. I mean it creates chunks based on _id itself and then assigns each shard a range of that.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Every shard stores around 33% of the data so what is your problem?